# Is it possible to install Microsoft SQL Server 2005 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2005

I've tried several attempts to install MS SQL 2005 standard on Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit but wasn't able to.

I've turn on all the IIS6 comptiable features. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but is it possible to install MS SQL 2005 on Windows 7? If you have done it, can you give me the step by step?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2009/05/14/sql-server-on-windows-7-rc-and-windows-server-2008-r2-rc.aspx :

"All editions of SQL Server 2005 SP3 and SQL Server 2008 SP1 are supported on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2."

"For SQL Server 2005, you need to be on SP3 to be compatible on Windows 7/WS08 R2"

Unfortunatly you'll need SQL install media that already has SP3 installed, as MS didn't introduce [slipstreaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipstream_(computing)) into SQL install media until 2008.

You can get MS SQL 2005 SP3 from MS [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ae7387c3-348c-4faa-8ae5-949fdfbe59c4&displaylang=en).  You may be able to do something with it?

Edit:

As Jack pointed out in his comment, a trick to simplify install appears to be:

> You can download SQL 2005 SP3. Run it then install SQL2005 then
>   install SP3 again. That will install SQL 2005 on Win7.

Comment: How can you install SP3 if you can't install MS SQL 2005?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. Like I said, you'll need to acquire SQL 2005 install media with SP3 already embedded in it.  If you don't have MSDN access or like, then I think you're best bet is going to be to contact the "Microsoft Supplemental Parts team" to see about getting a new disk with the SP3 already installed.  You can find their contact info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326246

Comment: You can download SQL 2005 SP3. Run it then install SQL2005 then install SP3 again. That will install SQL 2005 on Win7.

Comment: Thank you Jack for your last comment.  Saved me after ages of frustration trying to install SQL 2005 on Win7.  +1

Answer (score 0):

You have to install SQLEXPR first for support to SQL Server 2005. Then install SQL Server 2005 on a 32 bit operating system, like Windows 7.

I am sure that will install properly onto your system, but it is not compatible with 64 bit  operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

While I had tried many times (and racked my brains!) to install SP3 first, there wasn't an existing installation of SQL Server 2005 to install over it.

So, I changed the original SQL Server 2005 installation file's Compatibility settings to run as "Windows Server 2003" and it allowed me to install it onto Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

Then I installed SQL Server 2005 SP3 on top of that!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there are only two real hard requirements to get this to work.

1. It cannot be a 'Home' edition of Windows 7.
2. **You must activate .NET Framework 3.5 prior to installing SQL 2005 Express!** This is not available as an 'offline' installer from Microsoft.  In 'Control Panel - Programs and Features', click 'Turn windows features on and off', click the box in front of 'Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5', and click 'ok'.

I do believe an internet connection is required, and there is no need to reboot the computer.