# Installing SQL Server 2005 with advanced services on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install MS sql 2005 on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/95072/is-it-possible-to-install-ms-sql-2005-on-windows-7)

I  want to install SQL Server 2005 with advanced services (Reports support and Bussiness intelligence tools) on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition.

[I found out](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955725) that I need to install SQL Server 2005 SP3 before installing it.

I installed SP3 [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12413), and then downloaded [SQL Server 2005 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5897).

But still when I try to install, it says "not compatible".