# Installation issue for SQL Server 2005 on my Windows 7 Enterprise 32-bit

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install MS sql 2005 on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/95072/is-it-possible-to-install-ms-sql-2005-on-windows-7)

I'm having a problem installing a SQL Server 2005 on my Windows 7 Enterprise 32-bit.
The installation never completes. The error log file states I need to have IIS installed (I do and it is running). I did restart my pc after installing IIS.

I get a message stating that SP3 needs to be run after the install for compatibility issues, if the install never runs not sure how I can add it. I ran the SP3 anyway and it did not help. I do have .NET framework installed.

Summary error log from:
`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Summary.txt.`

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 9.00.4035.00 
============================== 
OS Version      : Professional Service Pack 1 (Build 7601) 
Time            : Thu Dec 27 10:52:51 2012 

LTDEL9C9H5R1 : The current system does not meet the minimum hardware requirements  
               for this SQL Server release.  
               For system requirements, see Hardware and Software Requirements, 
               in the readme file or in SQL Server Books Online.
LTDEL9C9H5R1 : Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) is either not
               installed or is disabled. IIS is required by some SQL Server features.  
               Without IIS, some SQL Server features will not be 
               available for installation. To install all SQL Server features,  
               install IIS from Add or Remove Programs in Control Panel or enable the
               IIS service through the Control Panel if it is already installed,  
               and then run SQL Server Setup again. For a list of features that depend
               on IIS, see Features Supported by Editions of SQL Server in Books Online.
LTDEL9C9H5R1 : To change an existing instance of Microsoft SQL Server 2005 to a  
               different edition of SQL Server 2005, you must run SQL Server 2005 
               Setup from the command prompt and include the SKUUPGRADE=1 parameter.
LTDEL9C9H5R1 : here was an unexpected failure during the setup wizard. You may  
               review the setup logs and/or click the help button for more information. 


 SQL Server Setup failed. For more information, review the Setup log file in %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Summary.txt. 


Time            : Thu Dec 27 10:55:25 2012
```

Comment: Tried the solution offered in 'Is it possible to install MS sql 2005 on Windows 7?'   Did not work.

Comment: More info please. :) What did you try from the other question/answer?  What happened?  Which exact version of SQL 2005 Server is it?  Which IIS components did you install?  Have you tried removing and reinstalling IIS?  Which version(s) of .NET are installed?

Comment: I Installation issue for SQL Server 2005 Enterprise issue. Ran SQL Serer 2005 SP3 then tried to run the set up for SQL Server 2005 did not work. Installed IIS 7.5, yes tried to remove and reinstall. Version 2.0 .net installed.

Answer (score 0):

According to MS KB article 920201 [You receive a warning message on the System Configuration Check page of the SQL Server 2005 Setup program on a computer that is running Windows Vista or a Server Core installation of Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920201):

You need to ensure specific components of IIS 7.x are installed.

The components required by SQL 2005 are:

```
Component - Folder

Static Content - Common HTTP Features 
Default Document - Common HTTP Features 
HTTP Redirection - Common HTTP Features 
Directory Browsing - Common HTTP Features 
ASP.Net Application - Development 
ISAPI Extension - Application Development 
ISAPI Filters - Application Development 
Windows Authentication - Security 
IIS Metabase - Management Tools 
IIS 6 WMI - Management Tools
```

More info on how to install components of IIS on Win 7 can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7).