# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation Error

Tags: installation, sql-server

I am desperate for some help installing SQL Server 2008 R2. It came as part of a software package from Rockwell Automation for their FactoryTalk View Studio software. I had the whole package working fine until last week (possibly due to a Windows update, though not sure which one). I decided I needed to uninstall FactoryTalk View Studio and reinstall. This required me to also uninstall SQL Server 2008 R2. I have tried 20 or more times to reinstall it but without success. I spent 2+ hours on the phone with Rockwell tech support trying to install but to no avail.

Here's the error description from the
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\summary.txt` file:

> SQL Server Browser configuration for feature 'SQL_Browser_Redist_SqlBrowser_Cpu32' was cancelled by user after a previous installation failure. The last attempted step: Starting the SQL Server Browser service 'SQLBrowser', and waiting for up to '900' seconds for the process to complete.

Comment: What version of Windows are you trying to install SQL onto?

Comment: You need at least SQL 2008 R2 _SP1_ to install it on Windows 7. Does your SQL install source include SP1? If not, then you need to get/create one.

Comment: I'm not sure how to figure that out? The files that are listed in the installation folder are labeled as follows: SQL_Server_Instal.bat, SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe, SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe, SQLServerInstall.exe. There two folders labeled: Microsoft.VC90.CRT, Microsoft.VC90.MFC. Both those folders have several .dll files and (1) one .manifest file. I don't see anything labeled SP1...

Comment: Then assume it doesn't.  Related SU question: [Is it possible to install Microsoft SQL Server 2005 on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/95072/is-it-possible-to-install-microsoft-sql-server-2005-on-windows-7), and here's a blog on [How to slipstream SQL Server 2008 R2 and a SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/petersad/archive/2011/07/13/how-to-slipstream-sql-server-2008-r2-and-a-sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-1-sp1.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I just downloaded the SP1 files from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727. Do I need to run all of the files? Even though I have 32-bit windows? Also, do I run these SP1 files and then try to install SQL Server 2008 R2 again? thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the  SQL Server "missuninstallation" Tool.

Then, I suggest you remove all SQL previous installations and everything, try to clean up everything. This (in several cases) can be done from "add or removing applications" but I remember remove them from the msi installer itself, because the tool and the windows method didn't work at all.

Of couse you have to stop and remove any installed service.

Then you must try to remove all references from the Windows Registry (regedit).

Then try again the reinstall.

I won't lie to you, sometimes it fixless, you've to back to a clean windows server/desktop installation.

I don't believe in it, but... good luck.

Comment: "wait the time that SQL needs to "rethink" what happens, as the message says. Not, is not a joke" -- I'm not understanding your answer... The 900 seconds is telling you how long it waited before giving up that step.